# Linux while read only reads first line of file

Tags: linux, loops, unix, fasta

I'm trying to subtitute headers in a file that looks like this:

> NC_037638.1 Apis mellifera strain DH4 linkage group LG1, Amel_HAv3.1, whole genome shotgun sequence
> GAGAGAATTAACTACCTTAACCTGAACCTAAACCTACCGATAACCTAACTCTAAACTATACCTTTAACCCCTAAACCCTA
> CACCTAAGTCCTAAACCAATAACCTTAACCCTAACAACTATATAAAACACTAACCTATAACCTAATCCCCTAACTACTAA
> ActactaacctaacctaaaactatatacctaacctaaaccttaCCCTAACCATAACCTATTACTCTAACCCTACCAAGAG
> CCTAAACCTAGAAACTTAACCCCTACAACCCTTAACCTTAACCTACACCTAACTACCTAATCCTACCTAACCtataccta

The file (Bee.fasta) has several headers (one for each sequence), the headers look like this:

> NC_037638.1 Apis mellifera strain DH4 linkage group LG1, Amel_HAv3.1, whole genome shotgun sequence

I want to change them into this:

LG1

```
*LG1 is just an example, depending on the line of the file it can be LG1, LG2, LG3, ...
```

The above code changes only the first header per iteration, leaving the latter headers unchanged.

Thanks in advance :)

I'm trying to subtitute headers in a file with the following code:

```
#!/bin/bash


grep 'LG' Be.fasta > old_headers.txt


while read header
do
        new_header=$(echo $header | awk -F ' ' '{print $8}')

        sed "s/$header/$new_header/g" Bee.fasta >> somefile.txt


done < old_headers.txt
```

The above code changes only the first header per iteration, leaving the latter headers unchanged.

Comment: I smell a computational biology major, lol.

Comment: As for your question; try echoing $header and $new_header every time through the loop. What does it output?

Comment: You have `Bee.fasta` in the sed line and `Be.fasta` in the grep line; is this correct?

Comment: Btw `sed` alone can do this in a single command; no script loops or anything needed:  `sed -E 's/^.*group *([^,]+).*$/\1/g' bee.fasta > somefile.txt` will look for lines containing the word "group", capture the tag following it (not including the comma), and replace those lines with the captured tag.

Comment: Thanks Jason! The sed command worked. I echoed &header and $new_header and it echoed correctly (I just removed those commands for simplicity). And yes, this is computational biology XD

Answer (score 1):

You're overthinking this. Plus looping over lines of text using bash is pretty much always a bad idea, performance-wise. Tools like `sed`, `awk` & `perl` were born to this job (text processing).

Since we know that the word `group` can only appear in headers and never in the gene-sequence Jason's `sed` in the comments should do all you ask for.

```
$ cat Bee.fasta 
NC_037638.1 Apis mellifera strain DH4 linkage group LG1, Amel_HAv3.1, whole genome shotgun sequence
GAGAGAATTAACTACCTTAACCTGAACCTAAACCTACCGATAACCTAACTCTAAACTATACCTTTAACCCCTAAACCCTA CACCTAAGTCCTAAACCAATAACCTTAACCCTAACAACTATATAAAACACTAACCTATAACCTAATCCCCTAACTACTAA ActactaacctaacctaaaactatatacctaacctaaaccttaCCCTAACCATAACCTATTACTCTAACCCTACCAAGAG CCTAAACCTAGAAACTTAACCCCTACAACCCTTAACCTTAACCTACACCTAACTACCTAATCCTACCTAACCtataccta
$ sed -E 's/^.*group *([^,]+).*$/\1/g' Bee.fasta > somefile.txt
$ cat somefile.txt 
LG1
GAGAGAATTAACTACCTTAACCTGAACCTAAACCTACCGATAACCTAACTCTAAACTATACCTTTAACCCCTAAACCCTA CACCTAAGTCCTAAACCAATAACCTTAACCCTAACAACTATATAAAACACTAACCTATAACCTAATCCCCTAACTACTAA ActactaacctaacctaaaactatatacctaacctaaaccttaCCCTAACCATAACCTATTACTCTAACCCTACCAAGAG CCTAAACCTAGAAACTTAACCCCTACAACCCTTAACCTTAACCTACACCTAACTACCTAATCCTACCTAACCtataccta
$
```

Comment: Thank You very much, your and Jason's command worked :) . It just left the suffix "unlocalized genomic scaffold" after some headers, but this was easy to remove using sed 's/unlocalized genomic scaffold//g' somefile.txt

Comment: @JakubLiu The "after some headers" part is odd - do your headers occasionally consist of several lines?